# SQL Constraints se encaixa como DML ou como DDL?

Tags: sql-server, constraint

DDL - Data definition language: é usado para criar e alterar tabelas (CREATE, ALTER, etc.), certo?

DML - Data manipulation language: é usado para a manipulação de dados das tabelas (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT).

As CONSTRAINTS entram na categoria de DDL?

Comment: Não me parece DML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, as contraints fazem parte dessa categoria. São usadas na criação da tabelas para para garantir regras sobre os campos que estás a criar, um exemplo é chave primaria ou o suporte a nulos.